# Angular 6, Firebase 3.9.0 - global is not defined in node_modules/firebase/auth.js

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angular6

So I'm in the process of building a web app with Angular 6, utilizing AngularFire2 and when I load up my app, I get this error:

```
auth.js:255 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/firebase/auth.js (auth.js:255)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../node_modules/firebase/firebase-browser.js (firebase-browser.js:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/app/core/auth.service.ts (auth.guard.ts:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/app/app.component.ts (main.js:156)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
./node_modules/firebase/auth.js @ auth.js:255
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:81
./node_modules/firebase/firebase-browser.js @ firebase-browser.js:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:81
./src/app/core/auth.service.ts @ auth.guard.ts:18
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:81
./src/app/app.component.ts @ main.js:156
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:81
./src/app/app.module.ts @ app.component.ts:9
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:81
./src/main.ts @ environment.ts:15
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:81
0 @ main.ts:14
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:81
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

I'm not sure if it's something with the version of angular I have or what, but I have an ionic app using these same two libraries with Angular 4 and it runs fine.

Here are the relevant packages:

```
  "@angular/animations": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.6.1",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^6.0.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^3.9.0"
```

am I missing something here with the versions of AngularFire and Firebase that I'm using?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js/issues/753

Comment: if anyone hasn't told you that they love you today...let that person be me. Thankyou so much that solved my problem!

Comment: ultimate solution

Answer (score 6):

As a temporary hack, go to pollyfill.ts file (you may find it in src folder of your application) and paste `(window as any).global = window;` at the end of file.